# Direct user to backup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to add a column to original table, so if I create a backup table

```
SELECT *
INTO [dbo].[table_BACKUP]
FROM [dbo].[table]
```

then how can I point the user to use the backup table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't.   Add the column to the backup table, then switch the names when you are ready.